# Saving data instantly, onClose, save button? Which is better in this situation

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore

In my GWT application, I have been saving everything that the user does instantly to the datastore in the background whenever they make changes. So far this has been fine because the things that the user can change aren't being changed a whole lot.

But now I have added a series of check boxes that the user can check & uncheck:

[image]

Would it be proper to save everything instantly to the database *everytime* the user checks/unchecks a box? The thing that's on my mind is reducing the amount of times my web application has to go to the server to save data. Facebook, Google, (and many many others) use a "Save" button whenever a user makes changes to a large amount of fields (say, to their user information).

I am trying to stay away from having a Save button, and so the thought came to mind about saving these values whenever the user closed or refreshed the page. I don't know if that's proper either (what if there is a loss of power, and their system shuts down!), but I know that I could use it like this:

```
public void onClose(CloseEvent<Window> event) {
    //save changes to the datastore
}
```

I'm torn between the three methods and don't know which path to take! Any information will be helpful

Thank you!

Comment: Are you able to use HTML5 features or Gears for your application? A good option would be to save changes *locally* then periodically sync to your server, this would avoid issues with constantly POSTing and open up the possibility to work offline – totally depends on your app though.

Comment: I can make changes on the client side without syncing anything, and the app will run fine until the user exits out of it and opens it again (Their previous changes wouldn't be saved). I don't _think_ I need to periodically sync anything or save changes locally, but I am now curious if that is possible in GWT.

Comment: edited and included the image that was intended for this post. (I didn't meet the 10 rep requirement at the time!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current system follows a really excellent design pattern which a lot of apps (web- and otherwise) are picking up lately: Eliminate the manual operation of 'saving'. I think you should stick with it.

That said, if you want to reduce the number of round-trips and server load, you can do a couple of things: You could restrict the number of saves-in-progress to one, so that if the user makes a change while you're waiting for a 'save' request to complete, you wait until that request completes before sending a new one. Or, you could start a timer when the user makes a change, and commit any changes when the timer expires - this is pretty much how GMail's auto-save of draft messages works.

Either way, *don't* rely on a close event to trigger sending state to the server: If the user's browser crashes, the close event won't fire and they'll lose all their changes.

Comment: I like the idea of a timer a lot, I now have something nifty to work on for the night! If I'm not relying on the close event, does that mean it shouldn't be used at all? If I were to use a timer, and the user quickly made changes and exited out of the browser the changes still wouldn't be saved if the timer hasn't run out I'd think. I'll poke around with it and get back to this question tomorrow morning once I know a little more. Thanks!

Comment: @trev It certainly wouldn't hurt to hook the close event, no. You may also be able to take advantage of some browsers' "are you sure you want to navigate away" dialog when they notice modifications to a form, though I'm not sure how they determine when to trigger that.

Comment: Accepted your answer. I'm not sure how they do that either, but that's another question later on down the road. Thank you again